Mouse is not smooth & jerks for precise movement
I'm not sure if it's the mouse, or the upgrade. Currently use Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Cinnamon Version 6.0.4, NVIDIA TU 106 [GeForce RTX 2070 Rev. A]
I cannot figure out how to make precise movements. I try to click one small area, like a box in my email, to choose it, and it misses the mark. It takes several attempts before I finally manage to get the pointer in the right spot. Maybe I'm not searching the right things. Any ideas?
